# R add row when value is missing

Tags: r, row

I'm having some trouble in editing my data frame.
First, my data:

```
X1 0.7
X2 0.05
X3 0.4
X5 0.9
```

What I want to do is add a row X4 with 0, so that my data looks like:

```
X1 0.7
X2 0.05
X3 0.4
X4 0
X5 0.9
```

I have a large data set, and the missing values are at random places. How do I find the missing values in R to add a row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `merge` with `all.x=TRUE`.  Based on the example provided in the OP's post, we extract the numeric part from the first column using `sub`, convert to `numeric`, get the sequence on the  `range` of values and `paste` with 'X' to create a new 'data.frame'.  This will be `merge`d with the old dataset, so that wherever there is no matching values for the first column in the old dataset, the corresponding elements in the second column will be filled by `NA`.  If needed, we can change those to 0 using `is.na` (but not recommended).

```
dM <- merge(data.frame(V1=paste0("X", Reduce(`:`, 
   range(as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', df1$V1)))))), df1, all.x=TRUE)
dM$V2[is.na(dM$V2)] <- 0
dM
#  V1   V2
#1 X1 0.70
#2 X2 0.05
#3 X3 0.40
#4 X4 0.00
#5 X5 0.90
```